# Is it possible to create tables within Angular ts files?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I have an array which holds different categories to compare different companies.  Depending on the user selection there may be 3 categories or 10 to display.  I am looking for a dynamic way to insert tables on demand depending on how many categories are selected.
Is there a library in Angular or around somewhere which can help with this task ?

I would rather not create 30 tables based off of categories and just hide the unwanted ones.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a grid and dynamically set the columns based on user selection as per your requirement.

I usually use ag-Grid library which is a fantastic easy to use library.
The free version should suffice for your requirment.
Have a look here,
https://blog.ag-grid.com/binding-and-updating-column-definitions-in-ag-grid/

Comment: I Appreciate the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't fit my scenario.  I need to be able to create and remove tables not only columns.  If you have any other suggestions I would be open to them.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured a work around for my issue.
I have all the categories in an Array, then I iterate through the array via *ngFor which will load a component

```
<div *ngFor="let category of Categories">
    <app-display-table-component></app-display-table-component>
</div>
```

for every category.  Inside each component I will show the data regarding the category name.

Thanks for the help guys.